# Pandas date-time conversion

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am fetching data from one of the file which has date stored as 
`20 March`
Using pandas I want to convert to `20/03/2020`

I tried using `strftime`,`to_datetime` using errors but still I am not able convert.

Moreover when I group by date it stores `date` column numerically like:
`1 January,1 February,1 March then 2 January,2 February, 2 March`

How do I resolve this?

Comment: So the year should be 2020 always?

Comment: Yes date should be 2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

def to_datetime_(dt):
    return pd.to_datetime(dt + " 2020")
```

to get timestamp in pandas with year 2020 always

Comment: I want to convert all the values in that column to ```20-03-2020``` for example.
Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can get them to pandas timestamp by using `df['date'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: to_datetime_(x))` with the above code

Comment: you can convert to whatever you want from there for example a datetime.date; `df['date'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: to_datetime_(x).date())`

Comment: for `20-03-2020` use `df['date'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: to_datetime_(x).strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))`

Answer (score 0):

Do,

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dates': ['1 January', '2 January', '10 March', '1 April']
})

df['dates'] = df['dates'].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d %B").replace(year=2020))

 # Output

    dates
0   2020-01-01
1   2020-01-02
2   2020-03-10
3   2020-04-01
```

Comment: what does `datetime` stands for? because when I am trying this it says datetime is not defined

Answer (score 0):

If `year` is always `2020` then use the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['20 March','22 March']})
df['date_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d %B')
```

If this shows year as `1900` then:

```
df['date_new'] = df['date_new'].mask(df['date_new'].dt.year == 1900, df['date_new'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(year = 2020))
print(df)
       date   date_new
0  20 March 2020-03-20
1  22 March 2020-03-22
```

Further you can convert the date format as required.

Comment: ```ValueError: day is out of range for month```
When I used the code in first code block,I got this error

Comment: Can you add some lines of your dataframe?